# Typo3 V9 Backendmodule View not found

Tags: typo3, backend, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

I try to write an backend module, i start up with the ext_tables.php and so an, i create an Controller that called correctly. When i click on my module in the backend i get an error:
`The technical reason is: No template was found. View could not be resolved for action "list" in class "Trendsetzer\Statistik\Controller\StatController".`
In the Typoscript Browser i checked the paths and all setted correctly: `EXT:ts_statistik/Resources/Private/Templates/` why they dont find the template file?
how can i show in which path they try to find the file?

Comment: do you have an `List.html` in `EXT:ts_statistik/Resources/Private/Templates/Stat/` (notice the `Stat` sub folder) directory?

Comment: yes, this file under this path exists (tried in different cases (lower, upper)) without any change, currently its expected `List.html`

Answer (score 0):

For frontend and backend you have 2 different typoscript paths.

`plugin.tx_myext` for frontend modules and `module.tx_myext` for backend modules.

Comment: Thanks, i know and my ts looks like: ````module.tx_ts_statistik {
 view {
  templateRootPaths {
   0 = EXT:ts_statistik/Resources/Private/Templates/
   1 = {$module.tx_ts_statistik.view.templateRootPath}
  }
  partialRootPaths {
   0 = EXT:ts_statistik/Resources/Private/Partials/
   1 = {$module.tx_ts_statistik.view.partialRootPath}
  }
  layoutRootPaths {
   0 = EXT:ts_statistik/Resources/Private/Layouts/
   1 = {$module.tx_ts_statistik.view.layoutRootPath}
  }
 }
 persistence < plugin.tx_ts_statistik.persistence
}````

Comment: please notice that mostly `tx_ts_statistik` is not working, your plugin path would be `tx_tsstatistik`

Comment: Thanks for this tip! I changed any configuration to `tx_tsstatistik` but the error with "````No template was found. View could not be resolved for action list in class````" is still there. How can i debug the path where they try to find the template file?

Answer (score 0):

When I started creating extensions, I often miss adding the typoscript to my root template.

You can add this by Module "Template" -> Your Root Page -> Edit the whole template record -> Tab "Includes" -> Include static (from extensions)

Comment: the static template is included and in object browser i see the config
`[module]

[tx_form]
[tx_tsstatistik]

[view]

[templateRootPaths]

    [0] = EXT:ts_statistik/Resources/Private/Templates/
    [1] = EXT:ts_statistik/Resources/Private/Templates/`

Answer (score 0):

Solution found, the namespace was incorrect: for extensions with underscore the namespace for extensionsn like `foo_bar` must be `Vendor\FooBar\...`

hope this helps anyone